# Visualforce - Preserve Whitespace in apex:outputText

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I've records with fields values containing more than one white space. The White spaces are preserved in the back-end but while displaying it on the Visualforce page, the white spaces are reduced to only one white space. I'm looking for something like `<pre>`. I tried with CSS property `white-space:pre/pre-wrap`but it didnt work. Using pre tag with apex tags are bringing in the alignment issues even with css property `display:inline-block`.
The lines displayed below for outputText with spaced replaced as `'&nbsp;`' in the class are displayed text as it is in the page, like **`A&nbsp;&nbsp;B`**

```
<apex:outputText escape="false"> {!myText}</apex:outputText>
```

OR

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!myText}"/>
```

Sample details: 
Original data: **`A  B`**

Expected: **`A  B`**

Actual: **`A B`**

Space after A in the above text has been trimmed to single whitespace.
I tried with  but no change.
Anyone faced the same issue and resolved? Please help.

Comment: if the answer is helpful to you, can you please mark it as answer?

Comment: I am getting also same problem but in different way.
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065440/render-from-bean-to-ui-have-issue-to-show-double-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Salesforce documentation:

If multiple spaces are required for some reason (e.g. formatting purposes), the `&nbsp;` entity must be used. However, in order for this entity to not itself be HTML escaped by apex, a proper "escape" option must be specified. Examples:

a) For the `outputText` tag, the "escape" attribute must be set to false. e.g.:

**Controller:**

```
comment = new CaseComment(CommentBody = 'There&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;are&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;between&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;each&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;word.\r\n\r\nThere is a blank line before this one.');
```

**Apex page:**

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!comment.CommentBody}"/>
```

b) selectList / selectOptions / selectOption:

If you wish to render non-breakable spaces in options in a select list, the attribute to set is a bit different; either by setting "`itemEscaped`" to "false" when using `apex:selectOption`, or, if creating `SelectOption` objects in the controller, call `setEscapeItem(false)` on each `SelectOption` that has the values with the `&nbsp;` entities.

Source: -https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194152&language=en_US

> Update

I tried with following code and it is working fine with `escape="false"`.

**Controller**

```
public String getMyText() {
    String myText = 'A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B';
    return myText;
}
```

**VF Page**

**Output**

A   B

Comment: I'm getting A&nbsp;&nbsp;B when I used apex:outputText escape="false"

Comment: @Vignex It is working for me. Please find my updated answer.

Comment: It worked...but the formatting is lost completely

Comment: @Vignex Can you please explain about the formatting issue, you experienced.